# Swift3 UIWebView delegate method not being called

Tags: swift, uiwebview

Code :

```
let termWebView = UIWebView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:20, width:320, height:400))
termWebView.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(termWebView)

        if let url = URL(string: “http://www.google.co.in”)
            termWebView.loadRequest(request)
        }


        func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
        {

        }

       func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!)
        {

        }
```

I created a simple webview and set the delegate.but the delegate methods are not being called.what is wrong with code?any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting something in as the url (e.g. https://www.google.com), `URL(string: “”)` is a failable initializer, so your webview most likely not loading.

Comment: what is `request` in your code that you have passed in `loadRequest()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
class TouchUIViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let termWebView = UIWebView(frame:CGRect(x:0, y:20, width:320, height:400))
    termWebView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(termWebView)
    let urlString = "http://www.google.co.in/"

    if let url = URL(string: urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)   {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        termWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }
  }

  func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

  }

  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
  {

  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Please mention the reason for down vote... I would like to improve it..

Comment: @PremaJannoti the note provided is misleading i.e. if you want to load content from HTTP source then you need to add App Transport Security Settings --> Allow Arbitrary Loads --> Yes in .plist file

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake.